# Разъезжаются элементы вёрстки

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, bootstrap

Здравствуйте. Есть у меня карточка с товаром. В ряд их должно быть 4 штуки и по мере уменьшения размера экрна должно быть 3-2-1. Это я сделал(ниже всё что у меня получилось сделать за 2-а дня), но вот наименование товара и цена при сжатии наезжают друг на друга, выходят за пределы элемента LI. 
Я понимаю это г***кодерство, поэтому решил обратиться сюда за помощью. Сам я не справлюсь. Заранее благодарю.

```css
.wraper {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.wraper p {
  margin: 0;
}
.wraper ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.wraper li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 24px;
  float: left;
  margin: 1%;
  text-align: center;
  width: 23%;
  height: 290px;
  text-align: center;
}
.wraper li img {
  width: 100%;
}

.one {
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
}

.two {
  float: right;
}

/*==========  Desktop First Method  ==========*/

/* Large Devices, Wide Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width : 1200px) {
}

/* Medium Devices, Desktops */
@media only screen and (max-width : 992px) {
 .wraper li{
 width: 29.33333%;
}
}

/* Small Devices, Tablets */
@media only screen and (max-width : 768px) {

 .wraper li{
 width: 46%;
}
 
}

/* Extra Small Devices, Phones */
@media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {
 .wraper li{
 width: 96%;
}
}

/* Custom, iPhone Retina */
@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
   <div class="wraper">
    <ul >
     <li>
      <img src="http://i066.radikal.ru/1607/48/796fa111ef2b.png" alt="">
      <div class="one">
       <span>LedCross</span>
       <p>Низкие "Белые"</p>
      </div>
      <div class="two">
       <span>1399 грн</span>
       <p>1599 грн</p>
      </div>
     </li>
     <li>
      <img src="http://i066.radikal.ru/1607/48/796fa111ef2b.png" alt="">
      <div class="one">
       <span>LedCross</span>
       <p>Низкие "Белые"</p>
      </div>
      <div class="two">
       <span>1399 грн</span>
       <p>1599 грн</p>
      </div>
     </li>
     <li>
      <img src="http://i066.radikal.ru/1607/48/796fa111ef2b.png" alt="">
      <div class="one">
       <span>LedCross</span>
       <p>Низкие "Белые"</p>
      </div>
      <div class="two">
       <span>1399 грн</span>
       <p>1599 грн</p>
      </div>
     </li>
     <li>
      <img src="http://i066.radikal.ru/1607/48/796fa111ef2b.png" alt="">
      <div class="one">
       <span>LedCross</span>
       <p>Низкие "Белые"</p>
      </div>
      <div class="two">
       <span>1399 грн</span>
       <p>1599 грн</p>
      </div>
     </li>
     <li>
      <img src="http://i066.radikal.ru/1607/48/796fa111ef2b.png" alt="">
      <div class="one">
       <span>LedCross</span>
       <p>Низкие "Белые"</p>
      </div>
      <div class="two">
       <span>1399 грн</span>
       <p>1599 грн</p>
      </div>
     </li>
     <li>
      <img src="http://i066.radikal.ru/1607/48/796fa111ef2b.png" alt="">
      <div class="one">
       <span>LedCross</span>
       <p>Низкие "Белые"</p>
      </div>
      <div class="two">
       <span>1399 грн</span>
       <p>1599 грн</p>
      </div>
     </li>
     <li>
      <img src="http://i066.radikal.ru/1607/48/796fa111ef2b.png" alt="">
      <div class="one">
       <span>LedCross</span>
       <p>Низкие "Белые"</p>
      </div>
      <div class="two">
       <span>1399 грн</span>
       <p>1599 грн</p>
      </div>
     </li>
     <li>
      <img src="http://i066.radikal.ru/1607/48/796fa111ef2b.png" alt="">
      <div class="one">
       <span>LedCross</span>
       <p>Низкие "Белые"</p>
      </div>
      <div class="two">
       <span>1399 грн</span>
       <p>1599 грн</p>
      </div>
     </li>
     <li>
      <img src="http://i066.radikal.ru/1607/48/796fa111ef2b.png" alt="">
      <div class="one">
       <span>LedCross</span>
       <p>Низкие "Белые"</p>
      </div>
      <div class="two">
       <span>1399 грн</span>
       <p>1599 грн</p>
      </div>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

[image: сама карточка]

[image: (всего 9)]

Comment: а почему именно списком ? блоками не удобнее будет ?

Comment: По другому у меня не вышло. Я делал блоками, но там у меня получилось еще хуже

Comment: по мне так в списках надо выводить списки а блокам то что должно выводится на показ , кесарю кесарево : cлесарю слесарево

Comment: http://codepen.io/Geyan/pen/bZaQEQ?editors=110  и вот я кстати не старался оссобенно , смотри пример

Comment: вот как у меня вышло https://jsfiddle.net/ugjsraym/

Comment: пользуйся codepen.io удобнее , далее по сетке в тот момент когда у тебя любой блок отваливается именно в этот момент создаёшь media запрос о том что эти блоки должны быть 49% и стоять в линию , что если не получится пиши

Answer (score 1):

серый фон уберите только ) как-то так на вскидку

```css
.wraper {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.wraper p {
  margin: 0;
}
.wraper ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.wraper li {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
  margin: 20px 2%;
  text-align: center;
  width: 21%;
  text-align: center;
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wraper li img {
  width: 100%;
}
.product-image {
  text-align: center;
}
.wraper li:after {
  clear: both;
  content: '';
  display: block;
}

.one {
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
  max-width: 60%;
}
.two {
  float: right;
  max-width: 40%;
}
/*==========  Desktop First Method  ==========*/

/* Large Devices, Wide Screens */

@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {}
/* Medium Devices, Desktops */

@media only screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  .wraper li {
    width: 29%;
  }
}
/* Small Devices, Tablets */

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .wraper li {
    width: 46%;
  }
}
/* Extra Small Devices, Phones */

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .wraper li {
    width: 96%;
  }
}
/* Custom, iPhone Retina */

@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="wraper">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <div class="product-image">
            <img src="http://i066.radikal.ru/1607/48/796fa111ef2b.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="one">
              <span>LedCross</span>
              <p>Низкие "Белые"</p>
            </div>
            <div class="two">
              <span>1399 грн</span>
              <p>1599 грн</p>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="product-image">
            <img src="http://i066.radikal.ru/1607/48/796fa111ef2b.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="one">
              <span>LedCross</span>
              <p>Низкие "Белые"</p>
            </div>
            <div class="two">
              <span>1399 грн</span>
              <p>1599 грн</p>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
           <div class="product-image">
            <img src="http://i066.radikal.ru/1607/48/796fa111ef2b.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="one">
              <span>LedCross</span>
              <p>Низкие "Белые"</p>
            </div>
            <div class="two">
              <span>1399 грн</span>
              <p>1599 грн</p>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="product-image">
            <img src="http://i066.radikal.ru/1607/48/796fa111ef2b.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="one">
              <span>LedCross</span>
              <p>Низкие "Белые"</p>
            </div>
            <div class="two">
              <span>1399 грн</span>
              <p>1599 грн</p>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="product-image">
            <img src="http://i066.radikal.ru/1607/48/796fa111ef2b.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="one">
              <span>LedCross</span>
              <p>Низкие "Белые"</p>
            </div>
            <div class="two">
              <span>1399 грн</span>
              <p>1599 грн</p>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="product-image">
            <img src="http://i066.radikal.ru/1607/48/796fa111ef2b.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="one">
              <span>LedCross</span>
              <p>Низкие "Белые"</p>
            </div>
            <div class="two">
              <span>1399 грн</span>
              <p>1599 грн</p>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="product-image">
            <img src="http://i066.radikal.ru/1607/48/796fa111ef2b.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="one">
              <span>LedCross</span>
              <p>Низкие "Белые"</p>
            </div>
            <div class="two">
              <span>1399 грн</span>
              <p>1599 грн</p>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
           <div class="product-image">
            <img src="http://i066.radikal.ru/1607/48/796fa111ef2b.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="one">
              <span>LedCross</span>
              <p>Низкие "Белые"</p>
            </div>
            <div class="two">
              <span>1399 грн</span>
              <p>1599 грн</p>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="product-image">
            <img src="http://i066.radikal.ru/1607/48/796fa111ef2b.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="one">
              <span>LedCross</span>
              <p>Низкие "Белые"</p>
            </div>
            <div class="two">
              <span>1399 грн</span>
              <p>1599 грн</p>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```